# Easy way of "adding" two large tables in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

Is there an easy way of adding the counts for each category in two large tables in **R**?

... where the tables don't all have exactly the same values present (though they will mostly overlap):

Small example of what I am trying to do. Set up some data:

```
  x1 <- c(5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 11, 2, 4, 9, 3, 5, 8, 2, 8, 5, 4, 8)
  x2 <- c(6, 10, 9, 17, 6, 7, 8, 11, 5, 12, 14, 5, 11, 7, 7)

  table(x1)
x1
 2  3  4  5  6  8  9 11 
 2  5  2  5  1  3  1  1 

 table(x2)
x2
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 14 17 
 2  2  3  1  1  1  2  1  1  1
```

Now I want to combine these tables as if I had done `table(c(x1,x2))`, getting:

```
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 14 17 
 2  5  2  7  3  3  4  2  1  3  1  1  1
```

But now imagine x1 and x2 are gone (and are really large so I really *don't* 
want to recreate them from the tables and actually do `table(c(x1,x2))`), 
all I want is to take the tables `t1` and `t2` and add their (often very large) counts... which I can do in several really clunky ways.

However, this seems like it should be both very common and very easily-solved 
problem (indeed, I reckon that `t1 + t2` ought to work for tables with categories 
of the same type) but searching for questions on every search term I could think 
of didn't find anything.

Have I missed a really simple and obvious way to do this?

Edit:

To clarify, something like this (which I did) is not 'simple and obvious' for what must 
be a very common operation with tables:

```
 m <- merge(t1,t2,by.x="x1",by.y="x2",all=TRUE)
 m[is.na(m)] <- 0
 oo <- order(m$x1)
 t12 <- m[oo,2]+m[oo,3]
 names(t12) <- m[oo,1]
```

In particular this is really no simpler nor easier to follow than the brute force approach.

Comment: You should have a look at `merge`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I did, before posting. I also played with it for a good while. I didn't see a good way to do what I wanted  (more easily than doing it by brute force). It's possible I missed something there, but in that case ... I need more of a hint than that.

Comment: Your life will be much easier if you use data frames instead of tables.  Tables are just named vectors, and in general, there are few R functions for aligning and combining named vectors, and many for data frames.

Comment: @hadley thanks; I am using a table for no other reason than it's the output of `table`; I'm happy to `as.data.frame` them as needed, but (following combining them) the named vector is sufficient for what I need; as a broader principle I think it's good advice, but I rarely use tables myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way using `tapply`:

```
tapply(c(t1,t2), names(c(t1,t2)), sum)
# 10 11 12 14 17  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
#  1  3  1  1  1  2  5  2  7  3  3  4  2
```

Here's if you want a sorted output:

```
w <- c(t1,t2)
# edit: Following G.Grothendieck's suggestion to simplify it further
tapply(w, as.numeric(names(w)), sum)
#  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 14 17 
#  2  5  2  7  3  3  4  2  1  3  1  1  1
```

Comment: Ah, neat. Yes, sorted output is needed. That second way will extend nicely to many tables with little effort.

Answer (score 1):

As @PaulHiemstra said, `merge`should do the job. I am not too familiar with it, but this code should work (though there might be more efficient ways to do it...)

```
x1 <- c(5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 11, 2, 4, 9, 3, 5, 8, 2, 8, 5, 4, 8)
x2 <- c(6, 10, 9, 17, 6, 7, 8, 11, 5, 12, 14, 5, 11, 7, 7)

tx1 <- table(x1)
tx2 <- table(x2)

df1 <- data.frame(names=names(tx1),values=as.vector(tx1))
df2 <- data.frame(names=names(tx2),values=as.vector(tx2))

mdf12 <- merge(df1,df2,by="names",all=TRUE)
mdf12[is.na(mdf12)] <- 0

counts <- mdf12[,2] + mdf12[,3]
names(counts) <- mdf12[,1]

counts[order(as.numeric(names(counts)))]
table(c(x1,x2))
```

I don't like the `is.na` step, but I do not know how to make it, that there are `0`in the first place instead of `NA`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I actually did something quite close to this, but it seems ridiculously complicated for what must be a very frequent operation with table.

Comment: Okay, sorry then to bring that. Maybe I can delete this post later, as you edited your post that you tried that complicated solution already before and @Arun posted a suitable solution (+1).

Comment: The fault here is mine; your answer covers *a* way to do it and in the absence of the information I later included in edit was a reasonable answer. I have upvoted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)
x1 <- c(5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 11, 2, 4, 9, 3, 5, 8, 2, 8, 5, 4, 8)
x2 <- c(6, 10, 9, 17, 6, 7, 8, 11, 5, 12, 14, 5, 11, 7, 7)

# Transform "Tables" to DataFrames & standardize column names
df1 <- as.data.frame(table(x1)) %>% select(x = x1, Freq)
df2 <- as.data.frame(table(x2)) %>% select(x = x2, Freq)  

# Merge tables & aggregate results
Ttldf <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(TtlFreq = sum(Freq))
```

> For a good, concise introduction to summarising and piping the Vignette is a great resource: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html
>
> For further information about ways to rapidly use summarization to further best effect, Markham's tutorial is very helpful: https://rpubs.com/justmarkham/dplyr-tutorial